# Validating a GUID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that checks to see if a value is an [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) valid GUID. In an attempt to do that, I'm using the following:

```
var id = '1e601ec7-fb00-4deb-a8bb-d9da5147d878';
var pattern = new RegExp('/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i');
if (pattern.test(id) === true) {
  console.log('We have a winner!');
} else {
  console.log('This is not a valid GUID.');
}
```

I'm confident that my GUID is a valid GUID. I thought I grabbed the correct regular expression for a GUID. However, no matter what, I always get an error that says its not a GUID.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You mustn't include the `/` characters in the regex when you're constructing it with `new RegExp`, and you should pass modifiers like `i` as a second parameter to the constructor:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', 'i');
```

But in this case there's no need to use `new RegExp` - you can just say:

```
var pattern = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
```

Comment: this is not fully working, try this: d1f9c98a-48b8-454e-68a2-08d76f610dac

Comment: that is not valid guid, therefore answer is correct

Comment: Geralt, why not? the length is correct, please explain.

Comment: Your example is not valid because it has an invalid value for the "variant" field. The "variant" is indicated by the first two or three bits of digit 17 (the first character of the fourth cluster).  Version 4 UUIDs must have either "10" (variant 1) or "110" (variant 2) as the most significant bits of the nibble (half-byte) indicated by the hex digit. This essentially means that the values for this hex digit are 8 (1000), 9 (1001), a (1010), b (1011) for variant 1, and c (1100) or d (1101) for var2 UUIDs. Your example UUID has "6" in this position, which isn't a valid value for this digit.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the RE above only validates var1 UUIDs; only var 1 are in common usage as var2 are legacy weirdness with an inconsistent byte order, are reserved for Microsoft COM, and therefore are not and should not be in common usage. Variant 2 UUID also only have a half the "randomness" due to losing one extra bit to the variant number (3 bits rather than 2). So just ignore them - use the regex above :)

Comment: @Timshel I think BruneX is right on this one. GUID has no specification, what you described is UUID standard. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is the only difference I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `RegExp` object, you can't add the modifiers as `/i`. You have to pass any them as the second argument to the constructor:

```
new RegExp('^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', 'i');
```

Or use the literal syntax:

```
/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i
```